# Json.NET serialization error

Tags: c#, json, json.net

This example code  is  a simplified version of my project, the _lockObject  is  legacy and cannot be removed I have the following class

```
 [DataContract(IsReference = true)]
 public class test 
 {
     [DataMember]
     private static object _lockObject = new object();
     [DataMember]
     private int num;
 }
```

And I try to serialize it using Json.NET as follows :

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
TextWriter text = new StringWriter(sb);

var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
serializer.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto;

serializer.PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.None;
serializer.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
serializer.TraceWriter = new MemoryTraceWriter();
serializer.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize;

serializer.PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.All;
serializer.TypeNameAssemblyFormat = System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.FormatterAssemblyStyle.Full;

var test = new test();
serializer.Serialize(text, test);
```

I get an error

> Error getting value from '_lockObject'

If i remove the static from _lockObject the serialization is successful

Comment: Why are you trying to serialize a private member that holds no meaningful data, used only for locking (I assume?) If you want to serialize the poorly named `num`, you should create a property.

Comment: This example code  is  a simplified version of my project, the _lockObject  is  legacy and cannot be removed

Comment: fine but, you don't need to serialize it. Another `new object`, when the JSON is deserialized would do just as well, the member variable carries no state.

Comment: This is a legacy class , the _lockObject must be serialzed

Comment: Explain why it must be serialized? Does some recipient of the JSON rely on that attributes presence?

Comment: The legacy business logic depends on it being serialized.

Comment: To put it another way, `_lockObject` is not a `DataMember` because it embodies no datum.

Comment: Really? Why have you made it `static` then? It can't be serialised as part of an instance and be static across all instances?

Comment: I have not maid it this way , this the way the legacy system is designed, I agree it is not the best design but this the way it is.

Comment: So, how does the legacy serialization work? The serialization that feeds the legacy business logic? What value does that put in the JSON for the `_lockObject` attribute?

Comment: The legacy system is based on WCF with DataContractSerializer

Comment: Hope this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17222900/serialize-object-along-with-static-member-variables-to-xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allowing a lock object to be deserialized into is a bad idea because it allows the locking mechanism to be defeated.  If you're just looking for a way to satisfy legacy serialization requirements without screwing up your locking mechanism, I propose that you introduce a dummy non-static member to stand in for the lock object on serialization and deserialization.  Define your class like this instead:

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class test 
{
    // DO NOT include this in serialization
    private static object _lockObject = new object();

    // This dummy object stands in for _lockObject for purposes of serialization
    // but is not referenced elsewhere in the code
    [DataMember(Name = "_lockObject")]
    private object dummy = new object();

    [DataMember]
    private int num;
}
```

The code can continue to reference the static `_lockObject`, while the external world sees the value of the dummy object instead, and is none the wiser.  Now the value of `_lockObject` cannot be inadvertently changed through deserialization.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that _lockObject is static field. Static fields are not serializable by default. And IMO you shouldn't serialize it.

Comment: This is not true , private members with no setters and getters are also serialized. Also if i remove the static from _lockObject the serialization works