# How to serialize xml static classes

Tags: xml, dll, unity-game-engine, static, serializable

I'm working on a dll for Unity. The code is to save the name and location of gameObject in an xml file. If the class is public, it works smoothly, but I volgio static. Only that static can not serialize it.

Can you help me?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace SaveSystemXML
{

    static class SaveSystem
    {
        private static string name;
        private  static Vector3 pos;
        private  static string path = "savingDati.txt";
        public static string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return name;
            }

            set
            {
                name = value;
            }
        }
        public static Vector3 Pos
        {
            get
            {
                return pos;
            }

            set
            {
                pos = value;
            }
        }

        public static void SaveInfo(Transform m_hInfo)
        {

            name = m_hInfo.name;
            pos = m_hInfo.transform.position;

            if (!File.Exists(path))
            {
                using (var file = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    var XML = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SaveSystem));

                    XML.Serialize(file, this); //this error because is a static class
                }
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293496/serialize-a-static-class